# GitLab CI/CD not taking latest code changes

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

So I have used GitLab CI/CD to deploy changes to private docker hub repo and using Digital Ocean droplet to run the server using docker but the changes are not being reflected in the docker container running on digital ocean. Here's the config file.

```
variables:
    IMAGE_NAME: codelyzer/test-repo
    IMAGE_TAG: test-app-1.0
stages:
    - test
    - build 
    - deploy

run_tests:
    stage: test 
    image: 
        node:16
    before_script:
        - npm install jest 
    script: 
        npm run test 

build_image: 
    stage: build
    image: docker:20.10.16
    services:
        - docker:20.10.16-dind
    variables:
        DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
    before_script:
        - docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS
    script:
        - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG . 
        - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG

deploy: 
    stage: deploy
    before_script:
        - chmod 400 $SSH_KEY
    script:
        - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY root@159.89.175.212 "
            docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS &&
            docker image prune -f && 
            docker ps -aq | xargs docker stop | xargs docker rm &&
            docker run -d -p 5001:5001 $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

Answer (score 1):

The digital ocean server wasn't fetching the latest image from the repository so I added docker prune as additional step to do.

```
deploy: 
    stage: deploy
    before_script:
        - chmod 400 $SSH_KEY
    script:
        - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY root@159.89.175.212 "
            docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS &&
            docker ps -aq | (xargs docker stop || true) | (xargs docker rm || true) &&
            docker system prune -a -f && 
            docker run -d -p 5001:5001 $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

Comment: Or it's possible to use `docker pull` instead of `prune`.